# How could I display sections in chunks of certain length in JavaScript/react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Currently I map through an array and for each item, I show a circle

```
    <div className='circlesCont'>
                  {launches.map((launch, index) => (
                    <div
                      className={`${'circle'} ${
                        index === slideNumber ? 'selectedPage' : ''
                      }`}
                      key={index}
                      id={index}
                      onClick={handleCirclePageClick}
                    ></div>
                  ))}
    </div>
```

I am trying to make it so only chunks of 8 items are being shown at a time.

For example, items **0 to 7**, then **7-13** etc.

Can this be done with logic inside the map container ?

Currently, I could just hide the items whose index is more than 8 and show the first 7, but can't come up with a way to get the required behavior.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.splice` to create dynamic chunks as required by you. Each of your `launches` array entry will contain a `isVisible` property based on which **you choose to render it or not**. I have created a sandbox for it. Here's the code for reference with comments :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const defaultState = [
  { name: "Hey1", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey2", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey3", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey4", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey5", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey6", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey7", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey8", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey9", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey10", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey11", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey12", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey13", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey14", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey15", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey16", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey17", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey18", isVisibile: true },
  { name: "Hey19", isVisibile: true }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

  const handleChunk = (start, end) => {
    // Get the chunk elements by using splice on copy of state;
    const chunkElements = [...state].splice(start, end - start);
    // For chunk elements, set the isVisible to false.
    chunkElements.forEach((ele) => (ele.isVisibile = false));
    // Make again a new copy of our state.
    const newState = [...state];
    // In our new state, update the visibility of the chunk elements.
    newState.splice(start, end - start, ...chunkElements);
    setState(newState);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <ul>{state.map((ele) => ele.isVisibile && <li>{ele.name}</li>)}</ul>
      <button onClick={() => handleChunk(3, 7)}>Chunk 3-7 it!!</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleChunk(8, 12)}>Chunk 8-12 it!!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above is a very raw implementation. It's really upto to you how you want to handle the visibility of state items but the chunking can be achieved as stated in the function.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chunk-it-4do9u?file=/src/App.js:0-1792)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice function to limit your map

```
 <div className='circlesCont'>
          {launches.slice(0,7).map((launch, index) => (
            <div
              className={`${'circle'} ${
                index === slideNumber ? 'selectedPage' : ''
              }`}
              key={index}
              id={index}
              onClick={handleCirclePageClick}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the page number in a state (and the number of items to display for each page in a const)

```
const [launchesPageIndex, setLaunchesPageIndex] = useState(0);
const itemsByPage = 7;
```

Then in order to implement the pagination you should replace

```
{launches.map((launch, index) => (
```

by

```
{launches.slice(launchesPageIndex * itemsByPage, launchesPageIndex * itemsByPage + itemsByPage).map((launch, index) => (
```

and when you want to go to the next page you only have to increment launchesPageIndex

```
setLaunchesPageIndex(launchesPageIndex + 1);
```